# Involution of unital based ring (Grothendieck ring of a fusion category)

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, monoidal-categories, fusion-categories

Let $A$ be a unital based ring in the sense of [[Ostrik, arXiv:math/0111139]](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139). As part of the data we have a base $B = \{b_i\}_{i\in I}$, and an involution $i \mapsto \bar i$ of $I$ whose induced map $\sum_i a_i b_i \mapsto \sum_i a_i b_{\bar i}$ is an anti-involution of $A$. Let $N_{ij}^k$ (same as $c_{ij}^k$ in Ostrik) be the constants in $b_i b_j = \sum_k N_{ij}^k b_k$. Assume $A$ is commutative, so every anti-involution of $A$ is also an involution of $A$.

**Definition.** $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $I$ *generated* by declaring $i\sim j$ if there exist $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k \in I$ such that $b_{r_1} b_{r_2} \cdots b_{r_k} = b_i + b_j + \cdots$

To make this definition look less out of nowhere, observe that the multiplication on $A$ descends to a group structure on $I/\sim$. Furthermore, one can show there's an isomorphism of abelian groups
\begin{equation}
{\rm Hom}(I/\sim, G) \cong \{ \varphi: I \rightarrow G~|~ \varphi(i) \varphi(j) = \varphi(k)~\forall i,j,k\in I ~\text{s.t.}~N_{ij}^k\neq 0\}.
\end{equation}
for any abelian group $G$.

Now, let $i \mapsto t.i$ be another possibly different involution of $I$ that induces an involution of $A$.

> **Question**: Let $i_0\in I$ be such that $t.i_0 \sim \overline{i_0}$. Can we always find $i_0', k\in I$ such that $i_0'\sim i_0$, $N_{i_0',t.i_0'}^k\neq 0$, $t.k=k$?

The answer is obviously "yes" if all $b_i$'s are invertible. Indeed, in that case, the equivalence relation $\sim$ is trivial, so $t.i_0\sim \overline{i_0}$ implies $t.i_0 = \overline{i_0}$ and we can take $k=0$ (we make the convention that $b_0$ is the unit of the ring).

(What I'm really interested in are the Grothendieck rings of braided fusion categories, which are commutative unital based rings. I don't know if categorical details will make any difference here, but please feel free to assume $A$ comes from a braided fusion category, or make additional assumptions like unitarity, modularity, or anything about dimensions.)

Thank you in advance! (And my apologies if this is too elementary!)

Comment: If you simply take $i_0'=i_0$, and $k=1$ (the tensor identity) then this is true. The reason for this is that the involution is the same as taking the dual object, and the tensor identity always appears in $X\otimes X^*$.
One more remark: the definition you gave will give you a group also in case the multiplication in the ring $A$ is not commutative. This group is known as the universal grading group and was studied by Gelaki Naidu Nikshych and other people.

Comment: @ehud Thank you for looking at this! Let me clarify a little. So there are two involutions. One is $i\mapsto\bar i$, which corresponds to duality, and the other is $i\mapsto t.i$. The hypothesis in my question was $t.i_0\sim\bar i_0$, which is weaker than $t.i_0=\bar i_0$. What I'd like to find is a $k$ for which $N_{i_0,t.i_0}^k\neq0$, which is different from $N_{i_0,\bar i_0}^k\neq 0$. I allowed for replacement of $i_0$ by any $i_0'$ in the same equiv class. I understand my question seems a little random but there's a reason I want to think about it. Hope you can provide some inspirations!

Comment: @EhudMeir Ah I guess what confused you was my notation $\sim$. $\sim$ is not an isomorphism of any sort, but rather a special equivalence relation I defined.

Comment: I understood that. I searched for an example of this, but still didn't find one. I tend to believe that there is an example where no such $k$ exists, but I do not have one in mind. The key here is to think about grading of a fusion category by a finite group. A canonical example would be the category of representations of a finite group $G$, which is graded by the dual of the center of $G$. In this case your equivalence relation boils down to say that $i\sim j$ iff the center acts in the same way on the two irreducible characters.